# Possible to speed up import process? Currently 500K rows of data takes 4 min and 45 sec

Tags: vba, import-from-excel

I'm importing a specific sheet (with about 500K rows) in a workbook into the current workbook that I'm working with. Import works fine consecutively by deleting the current sheet before importing again but it is really slow.

I tried to add:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

from [link](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/) to my code, but import time didn't really improve.

Any tips on how I can improve import time substantially?

Here's my code:

```
Public filespec As Variant

Sub import_click()
    filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    If filespec = False Then Exit Sub

    Call deletedatasheet
    Call import

    MsgBox "Data imported", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub import()

Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim rd As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If wsMaster Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet
        Set rd = wsMaster.Range("A1")
        wsMaster.Name = "Reviewed"
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
        Sheets("Reviewed").Activate
        Cells.Copy rd
        wb.Close
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

Sub deletedatasheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = "Reviewed" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try copying just the used range insetad of the full 1 million+ rows and columns (untested):

```
Option Explicit

Public filespec As Variant

Sub import_click()
    filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If filespec = False Then Exit Sub

    Call deletedatasheet
    Call import
    MsgBox "Data imported", vbInformation
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub importSheet()
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim rd As Range, wb As Workbook

    xlEnabled False
    If wsMaster Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet
        wsMaster.Name = "Reviewed"
        Set rd = wsMaster.Range("A1")
        wsMaster.EnableCalculation = False

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
            With wb.Sheets("Reviewed")
                .EnableCalculation = False
                .UsedRange.Copy
                rd.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                rd.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                .EnableCalculation = True
            End With
        wsMaster.EnableCalculation = True
        wb.Close
    End If
    xlEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub xlEnabled(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = opt
        .ScreenUpdating = opt
        .DisplayAlerts = opt
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, combined with `import_click()` - I included it in my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Public filespec As Variant, file As String
Sub import_click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
file = Dir(filespec)
If filespec = False Then Exit Sub
file = Dir(filespec)
If Evaluate("ISREF(Reviewed!A1)") Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Reviewed").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Call import
MsgBox "Data imported", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub import()

Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, lr As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add().Name = "Reviewed"
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=filespec
lr = Workbooks(file).Sheets("Reviewed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reviewed").Range("A1:Z" & lr).Value = Workbooks(file).Sheets("Reviewed").Range("A1:Z" & lr).Value
Workbooks(file).Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: After around 3 min, I got the following error message "overflow" and it redirecting to "lr = Workbooks(file).Sheets("Reviewed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: what version of Office do you have ?

Comment: @Saud yes I tried to generate worksheet with 500k rows and 50 columns, and then use my code and I get the same error. I guess Excel is not the best tool to process such amount of data, even though it has limit 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.